# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup -- Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to scrape the code below, to retrieve the portions that say "SCRAPE THIS" and "SCRAPE THIS AS WELL". I have been playing around with it for a few hours with no luck! Does anyone know how this can be done?

`<div class="mod-body add-border"> <div class="mod-inline mod-body-A-F"> <h4>SCRAPE THIS</h4> <div class="mod-body"> <ul class="list"> <li>SCRAPE THIS AS WELL</li> </ul> </div> </div>`

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = """<div class="mod-body add-border"> <div class="mod-inline mod-body-A-F"> <h4>SCRAPE THIS</h4> <div class="mod-body"> <ul class="list"> <li>SCRAPE THIS AS WELL</li> </ul> </div> </div>"""
x = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
print(x.find('h4').get_text())
print(x.find('li').get_text())
```